# closeout the javascript code properly

Tags: javascript

I've debugged 99% of the code but I'm stuck at the closure brackets...?

```
// Create privatized scope using a self-executing function
(function(){


// Variable initialization (DO NOT FIX ANY OF THE BELOW VAR's)
var resultsDIV = document.getElementById("results"),
    searchInput = document.forms[0].search,
    currentSearch = ''
;

// Validates search query
var validate = function(query){

    // Trim whitespace from start and end of search query
    while(query.charAt(0) = " "){
        query = query.substring(1, query.length);
    };
    while(query.charAt(query.length-1) === ""){
        query = query.substring(0, query.length-1);
    ;

    // Check search length, must have 3 characters
    if(query.length < 3){
        alert("Your search query is too small, try again.");

        // (DO NOT FIX THE LINE DIRECTLY BELOW)
        searchInput.focus();
        return;
    };

    search(query);
};

// Finds search matches
var search = function(query) {

    // split the user's search query string into an array
    var queryArray = query.join(" ");

    // array to store matched results from database.js
    var results = [];

    // loop through each index of db array
    for(var i=0, j=db.length; i<j; i++){

        // each db[i] is a single video item, each title ends with a pipe "|"
        // save a lowercase variable of the video title
        var dbTitleEnd = db[i].indexOf('|');
        var dbitem = db[i].tolowercase().substring(0, dbTitleEnd);

        // loop through the user's search query words
        // save a lowercase variable of the search keyword
        for(var ii=0, jj=queryArray.length; ii<jj; ii++){
            var qitem = queryArray[ii].tolowercase();

            // is the keyword anywhere in the video title?
            // If a match is found, push full db[i] into results array
            var compare = dbitem.indexOf(qitem);
            if(compare !== -1){
                results.push(db[i]);
            };
        ;
    ;

    results.sort();

    // Check that matches were found, and run output functions
    if(results.length = 0){
        noMatch();
    }else{
        showMatches(results);
    };
};

// Put "No Results" message into page (DO NOT FIX THE HTML VAR NOR THE innerHTML)
var noMatch = function(){
    var html = ''+
        '<p>No Results found.</p>'+
        '<p style="font-size:10px;">Try searching for "JavaScript".  Just an idea.</p>'
    ;
    resultsDIV.innerHTML = html;
};

// Put matches into page as paragraphs with anchors
var showMatches = function(results){

    // THE NEXT 4 LINES ARE CORRECT.
    var html = '<p>Results</p>', 
        title, 
        url
    ;

    // loop through all the results search() function
    for(var i=0, j=results.length; i<j; i++){

        // title of video ends with pipe
        // pull the title's string using index numbers
        titleEnd = results[i].indexOf('|');
        title = results[i].subString(0, titleEnd);

        // pull the video url after the title
        url = results[i].substring(results[i].indexOf('|')+1, results[i].length);

        // make the video link - THE NEXT LINE IS CORRECT.
        html += '<p><a href=' + url + '>' + title + '</a></p>';
    };
    resultsDIV.innerHTML = html; //THIS LINE IS CORRECT.
};

// The onsubmit event will be reviewed in upcoming Course Material.
// THE LINE DIRECTLY BELOW IS CORRECT
document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(){
    var query = searchInput.value;
    validqte(query);

    // return false is needed for most events - this will be reviewed in upcoming course material
    // THE LINE DIRECTLY BELOW IS CORRECT
    return false;
};

})();
```

School Assignment almost completed 1 final syntax error remains:

How do I closeout this javascript code properly? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: @PupaRebbe he is trying to invoke the function, that is why he has the `()`s.

Comment: Aaron, if my answer solved your problem, please accept it by pressing the check box next to my answer. It will mark your question as answered and help me out in the process. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to close out your second `while` statement:

```
while(query.charAt(query.length - 1) === "") {
    query = query.substring(0, query.length - 1);
} // Note bracket here (not ;)
```

You also need brackets to close your `for` loops:

```
for(var i = 0, j = db.length; i < j; i++) {
    .
    .
    .
    for(var ii = 0, jj = queryArray.length; ii < jj; ii++){
        .
        .
        .
    } // Note bracket here
} // And here
```

**A side note:** you do not need to close out blocks of code with `;`s. As I showed above, `while` and `for` blocks do not need to be closed with a `;`. `if` - `else` statements do not need to be closed with a `;` either.